# How to use GridSplitter to correctly resize the controls?

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, grid, gridsplitter

Below is my code:

```
<Window 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"

        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="673" Width="1008" >

    <Grid Margin="0, 0, 8, 8">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="8, 8, 0, 0" />
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Control}}" />
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Control}}" />
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Control}}" />
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Control}}" />
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Control}}" />
        </Grid.Resources>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="7"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox x:Name="original_text" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" Text="text1"  />

        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Background="AntiqueWhite" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />

        <Grid x:Name="grid2" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="True" Content="aaaa" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <CheckBox IsChecked="True" Content="bbbb" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" />

            <CheckBox IsChecked="True" Content="cccc" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" />
            <CheckBox IsChecked="False" Content="dddd" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />

            <Label Content="aaa" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20, 0, 0, 0" />
            <ComboBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="24, 0, 0, 0">
                <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">eeee</ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>
            <Label Content="asdf" Grid.Column="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20, 0, 0, 0" />
            <ComboBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="24, 0, 0, 0" IsEditable="True" Width="130">
                <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">fff</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>ggg</ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="4">

            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>

        <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" Grid.Row="3" FontFamily="Courier New" Text="text2" />
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

The behavior that I want to implement is that when the user drags the GridSplitter, he can resize text1 and text2. The center part grid2 should remain its original size. Is this possible? Hope someone can point me the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Window 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"

        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="673" Width="1008" >

    <Grid Margin="0, 0, 8, 8">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="8, 8, 0, 0" />
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Control}}" />
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Control}}" />
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Control}}" />
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Control}}" />
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Control}}" />
        </Grid.Resources>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="7"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="100"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox x:Name="original_text" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" Text="text1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />

        <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Background="AntiqueWhite" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />

        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid x:Name="grid2">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="True" Content="aaaa" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <CheckBox IsChecked="True" Content="bbbb" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" />

                <CheckBox IsChecked="True" Content="cccc" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" />
                <CheckBox IsChecked="False" Content="dddd" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />

                <Label Content="aaa" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20, 0, 0, 0" />
                <ComboBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="24, 0, 0, 0">
                    <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">eeee</ComboBoxItem>
                </ComboBox>
                <Label Content="asdf" Grid.Column="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20, 0, 0, 0" />
                <ComboBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="24, 0, 0, 0" IsEditable="True" Width="130">
                    <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">fff</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>ggg</ComboBoxItem>
                </ComboBox>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="4">

                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>

            <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" Grid.Row="1" FontFamily="Courier New" Text="text2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thank you! It works and you've pointed me the right direction.